# Github API callback URL

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, github-api

I'm trying to write a github client for iOS in Swift. So far I managed to understand how OAuth 2.0 works. 
But the thing I don't understand is what callback URL should I enter (for user to be redirected after dealing with OAuth), when registering my app at OAuth applications list. I add URL scheme like "mycustomapp" in Info.plist, then I enter "mycustomapp://" in the callback url field on developer.github website, but it says, that this url is invalid. What URL should I use?

Comment: What is the full url including your custom app scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution to this issue on a oAuthSwift wiki page. 
Some API do not accept custom url scheme (ex: myapp://) into callback URL (ex: Linkedin oauth v2, Twitter oauth v1), only http is accepted.
So I used a URL with http scheme, which redirects to my custom one.
I entered `http://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/myappname` as a callback and inside my app I redirect to `oauth-swift://oauth-callback/myappname`
Code could be found here https://github.com/dongri/oauthswift.herokuapp.com